# How do I plot histograms of a dataset from a CSV file?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, import

I have a CSV file with over than 2000 rows.
!(
[image: Example of what one row looks like]

I'm trying to plot separate histogram for off-peak, on-peak and mid-peak consumptions but I cannot figure out how. How do I plot these three separate histograms using this CSV file?

Comment: With that much data you might consider `SmoothKernelDistribution`.  That way you can place those "smoothed histograms" on a single graph which makes for more direct comparisons among the consumption time categories.

Answer (score 2):

Group the data by the last three columns using [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html)

```
groupedData = GatherBy[data, FromDigits[#[[3 ;;]]] &];
```

Use the second column of the data in the [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)

```
histogramData = groupedData /. x_?VectorQ :> x[[2]];

Histogram[histogramData, Automatic, "PDF"]
```

[image]